# Fill and redrill curtain holes (concrete ceiling)

Tags: concrete, ceiling

I have an apartment where previous owners have done a lot of holes on the concrete ceiling for very long a curtain rail. They removed the curtain and the plugs and sealed the holes with single no more nails (very soft material, easy to remove. They did not filled the holes deep).

**I want to full restore the ceiling so a new type of curtain can be installed drilling in any zone and installing new plugs/anchors withouth the risk of the plug to be loose.** **How can I fully restore the ceiling?**

I've done this very same question to many constructors and I have basically these possible answers.

1.- Clean the holes of dust and any material and fill the holes with epoxy (a product like sikadur 31). Epoxy is harder than concrete and it will support redrilling.

2.- Clean the holes of dust and any material, apply concrete bonding agent (a product like sikadur 32) then apply repair mortar based on hydraulic expansive cement. Concrete bonding agent would help to create a monolithic between the original concrete and the repair. Redrilling would be possible after a long dry-cure period (weeks).

3.- Opposite to #1: even though epoxy would support redrilling the drill tip would tend to drift to the softer area which is concrete, so you won't be able to drill in the same spot again. Solution like #2 is better.

4.- Opposite to #2: the repair zone would fail on a redrill attempt. Two posibilities: a) the whole repair patch would chip out b) it would be possible redrill and put a new plug/anchor at first, but eventually with some weight load (like a curtain) the plug would strip out of the hole. Solution #1 is better.

5.- Worst of all: there is not possible solution at all (except redrill a bigger holes where possible). This option does not work for me.

Curiosly constructors supporting options #1 & 2 have told me that they have tried these solutions with success.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Unless the curtain rods were removed by tying a rope to them and a truck, those holes should be near perfect condition for new anchors.  Drilling cement usually not that nice.

Comment: I will sell the property and what the new owner have the posibility to drill anywhere. With current ceiling state would not be possible to sell the property.

Comment: List the pre-drilled curtain holes as a feature.

Comment: @crip659 not funny :-\

Comment: I think the detail in comment that you plan to re-sell the property is rather important, because there are a couple of hacks/bodges you could do to simply install other curtain rail that do not solve the "real issue". But anyway: Iv'e been in the situation where an existing hole is to large for the same anchor that was previously used and I simply went for next anchor size, upsized the screws and enlarged the holes in mounting hardware. At the time solved the issue in minutes using what I already had in my toolbox.

Comment: Currently there is another curtain (roller duo). Unfortunately it is not the best to cover the sun during summer so the new owner could be tempted to change it for a completely different one with different anchoring system. That's why I want to repair the ceiling as best as possible.

Comment: My best guess is that if new owner drills in the same spot after the repair done there is a chance it works or it will take a time until it actually fails

Comment: If possible I would plug the hole with a tight fitting wood dowel then mount the new curtain hangers to that with a trim piece to hide the plugs. You can place some adhesive on the dowels before tapping them in place.

Answer (score 1):

Not solving the problem as seen - filling , then making even more holes - my solution is (and has been) to fix a piece of wood, appropriate width, length and importantly thickness under (over?) the whole ceiling area affected. Solid wood works, as will ply. The thickness will accommodate the screws to be used to fix curtain rails, etc. The wood can be fixed with screws into the concrete where there is a lot of 'meat'. The whole lot can be painted appropriately, and the finished job will hardly show.